# Inside sliding shower door keeps returning to its same spot

Tags: shower

Sliding shower door is not staying closed. The outside door is working fine I can move it in either direction and it will stay in place but the inside one moves back to its original spot if I move it. How could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does the bottom/top roll on rollers?  If so one is a tiny bit higher/lower than the other one.  It is running down hill.

Comment: Refer to the installation instructions on how to get the track level.  It is moving because the track is out of level.  The glass wants to roll to the low side.   The other possibility is to  add a small piece of rubber to the bottom guide, to provide friction to resist the rolling .

Comment: There is one in the basement that does not have this issue. The basement one has a plastic piece that clasps the door or secures it when it's moved. Not sure where I can get this plastic piece

Comment: Interesting that one door moves and the other doesn't.  You should examine them closely to understand why.  That will help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.